# After restore sql backup through java how to delete that backup through java

Tags: java, mysql

I am Basically a Programmer and Want to delete backup of sql after restored

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**File::delete**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#delete()) or evern [**File::deleteOnExit**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#deleteOnExit()):

```
File file = new File("path");
file.delete();
```

Comment: Sorry Bro I already try this function. **Please** Give me another Answer

Comment: what did you mean @VishavJeetSinghSodhi why this solution not work?